# Limiting overall disk size allocation in vsphere?

Tags: vsphere, vcenter

Is there a way in VCenter to limit the max overall size of a VM in a datastore? For example, if a user makes too many snapshots, it could, in theory, consume the entire datastore.

Comment: Yes. It is called Quotas: https://pubs.vmware.com/vcd-820/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.vmware.vcloud.user.doc%2FGUID-F0A7FCE9-27D3-489F-9ACC-B1518E80C268.html

Comment: Thank you for the document for VMware vCloud Director but I need this to work for basic VCenter or ESXi.